# Cell Diagram or Representation of an Electrochemical Cell

Tags: electrochemistry

What is meant by anode half cell and cathode half cell in Cell diagram , I know that at Anode oxidation takes place and at cathode reduction takes place But the main concept which is troubling me is what is meant by half cell of both anode and cathode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anode is producing electrons. It does not work as an ordinary chemical reaction, since it produces electrons, which are not weighable stuff. The chemical equation taking place at the anode contains electrons, which never occurs in usual chemical reactions. For this reason, this equation is called a half-equation.

The cathode is consuming electrons coming from the anode. It does not work like an ordinary chemical reaction, since it consumes electrons, which are not weighable stuff like a metal or an acid. The chemical equation taking place at the cathode contains electrons, which never occurs in usual chemical reactions. So this equation is called a half-equation.

A half-equation can never exists alone. It must be accompanied by another half-equation. The same number of electrons are created on the anode side, which are consumed in the cathode side.